# How to lock database table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, linq, locking

Our project is running on ASP.NET, we are using Entity Framework with `LINQ` (lambda syntax) and we need to prevent from inserting into table at same time. I tried to use `ReaderWriterLock` class, but it works only in one session (when opened more tabs in browser), but not in more different browsers. I also read about creating table with timestamps (not sure if it can solve our problem) or use transactions, but do not now exactly how to use it in web application with `LINQ`.

Can you tell me please how to handle this exclusive write access in ASP.NET?

Comment: "How to lock database table in ASP.NET" - Don't. Let the database do what its good at. Perhaps you could state the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than a perceived solution.

Comment: i will describe you a situation : there is capacity for one request, but in the same time two different users accept request to register into this capacity...how to prevent from this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  `ReaderWriterLockSlim` could be a good choice, but if you want that ANY thread/process may share the same lock, the whole `ReaderWriterLockSlim` must be a static member.

That is, your class should look like this:

```
public class Class1
{
     private readonly static ReaderWriterLockSlim _lock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
}
```

### Important note

Using an application layer lock you'll be able to lock your own application threads in order to limit one thread to access the database at once. But other applications (not the ASP.NET one, or another application in another application pool also on IIS) may be able to access the database in parallel either doing reads and writes.

If you want a 100% effective solution, you *must* use database transactions. If SQL Server is the RDBMS, you can go for a transaction with `Serializable` isolation level:

> Volatile data can be read but not modified, and no new data can be
>   added during the transaction.

[Learn more here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: A ReaderWriterLockSlim  isn't going to lock a database table, now is it?

Comment: @MitchWheat I can expand my answer in the fact that you can't absolutely lock a table from the application layer. But using a lock, you can prevent your own program to access the database from multiple threads.

Comment: you're suggesting a solution, but we don't actually know what the OP's problem really is.

Comment: what we need is to prevent multiple writes from multiple threads withit one asp.net application...this Matias advice to use static ReadWriterLockSlim seems work fine